# Substitute simple variables in static assets

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'd like to substitute a few simple variables (e.g. a version number, or a CDN URL prefix) in static assets (html, css, js) at build time. Play 2.x itself isn't able to do this, but perhaps there is a generic sbt task that does variable interpolation in files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [sbt-editsource](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=https://github.com/bmc/sbt-editsource&ei=VPydUIifJ4Xe4QST5YGABA&usg=AFQjCNEKGUNa6MNkF33bVJmtkBvxLOaZTw&sig2=9OcQYw8ZNK5ZohNnCjkNug) plugin. It does simple variable substitutions on the source text. You will need to set the sources directory to where your static assets are. Here is a [detailed guide](http://software.clapper.org/sbt-editsource/).

Comment: This is not working now, I have tried it and it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know your needs and probably Kim's answer is good enough you can also make CDN configurable via application.conf + small resolving method:

`conf/application.conf`:

```
cdn.cdn1="http://cdn1.domain.tld/"
cdn.cdn2="http://cdn2.domain.tld/"
```

`Application.java`

```
public static String cdnResource(String cdnId, String filePath) {
    return Play.application().configuration().getString("cdn."+cdnId) + filePath;
}
```

Usage:

```
<script src='@Application.cdnResource("cdn1", "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<img src='@Application.cdnResource("cdn2", "template/images/logo.png")' alt="" >
```

Comment: This won't work for static assets--unless there is a way to have templates evaluated at build time?